# How do I ask again to solicit for a better answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question and it was never actually directly answered.  I did get one response that featured an alternative to the problem, but it didn't answer the question directly.  I am wondering what is the appropriate way to ask the question anew or to somehow make the question become active again without offending the moderators?

[How could I automatically delete accounts with a given criteria?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69097/how-could-i-automatically-delete-accounts-with-a-given-criteria)

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer that was given?

Comment: Check out this question which answers on how to get more attention for your question http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-do-i-get-more-response-until-i-get-the-correct-solution

Comment: I accepted the answer because it was one method of preventing spam users from signing up with only two characters.  Should I not have accepted it?  I am not clear on this and is the reason I am asking here, please clarify.  On the other hand, my question was really asking how to delete a set of users who match a given criteria, not prevent users from signing up.

Comment: @2-Stroker Yes, I checked out those links. They were educational.  Although no one directly answered his question either. (at least at this moment in time). Your link to stackoverflow at the other link you post above was even more informative. They mention what probably is the case here, that since it was not an easy and quick answer, it was shuffled to the bottom by newer and easier questions to answer.  Of course, that link got a -1 rating (at least it is at this moment) so not sure why you would think it was a good reference.  I gather then that this question will get negative rating.

Comment: By accepting that answer your are telling others that this person has answered your question. It will also no longer show up in the unanswered list. I for one look to for a green checkmark and if there is one I move on. I don't read every single answer and comment. If you need to get more attention, uncheck the answer, comment as to why it is no longer correct, revise your question to better clarify and then throw a bounty on it.

Comment: I understand much better now how this works.  I will follow and do what you recommend.  @NigelWaters Your comment really should have been the answer.  Kiamlaluno comes along and copies everything you stated but makes it an answer instead of a comment after you had posted all the same information.  No shame.  If you would post the same information in the form of an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That's ok. Kiamlaluno needs the points :P You can award it to him. lol

Answer (score 2):

The steps I would follow are:

- Unmark the currently accepted answer
- Edit the question to make it clearer, or to get a more focused answer
- Offer a bounty

Once done a step, I would wait some days before doing the next one.

Notice that:

- Since you accepted an answer, the question doesn't appear between the answers without an accepted answer. Those who look for questions to answer would not find your question in the list they probably look when they want to answer. Even in the case somebody would notice your question, they would not try to answer it, since you accepted an answer, which probably tell them that you already moved over to a different issue.
- When editing the question to get a more focused answer, the meaning of the question should not be changed so much that the given answers don't apply anymore. For example, you could incorporate the information you have given in comments, especially those that have been given for an answer.